# Python Regular Expression MULTILINE Not Finding Anything

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like

```
line = "... ... constant0 username@domain\r"
```

I need to extract domain

```
matchObj = re.match( 'constant\d+\s+(\w+)\@(\w+)', line, re.M|re.I)
```

`matchObj`  is always returning `None`. What is that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 6):

From the docs on [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> Note that even in [MULTILINE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.
>
> If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use [search()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead (see also [search() vs. match()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)).

`re.match()` does not locate a match anywhere in the string, whereas `re.search()` will. You will want to use `re.search()` (most of the time) instead.

Observe:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "... ... constant0 username@domain\r"
>>> matchObj = re.match( 'constant\d+\s+(\w+)\@(\w+)', line, re.M|re.I)
>>> matchObj # None
>>> matchObj = re.search('constant\d+\s+(\w+)\@(\w+)', line, re.M|re.I)
>>> matchObj
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10ce84470>
>>> print matchObj.group(0)
constant0 username@domain
>>> print matchObj.group(1)
username
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.search` not `re.match`, `re.match` is used to match at the start of the string.

[**search() vs. match()**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the **beginning** of
>   the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match **anywhere** in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).

Answer (score 1):

`re.match` only matches at the beginning of the string. `re.search` matches anywhere. As per the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), don't just add a `.*` at the beginning of re.match, use `re.search` to get the optimization! (`re.search` makes a quick loop in c to only check parts of the string that match the first character. If it starts with an ambiguous character, it has to go all the way to the end of the string and backtrack.)

And [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) is a gentler and (I think) generally better introduction to most of Python's regular expression functionality.